# SQL Server 2012 service not starting automatically

Tags: service, sql-server-2012

I have multiple SQL Server instance and I want to start service automatically for each when system starts. So I choose services state to automatically but it does not start automatically.

Here is the error log of one of the SQL Server instances

```
2018-07-12 17:55:30.96 Server      SQL Server detected 1 sockets with 2 cores per socket and 4 logical processors per socket, 4 total logical processors; using 4 logical processors based on SQL Server licensing. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2018-07-12 17:55:30.96 Server      SQL Server is starting at normal priority base (=7). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2018-07-12 17:55:30.97 Server      Detected 16155 MB of RAM. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2018-07-12 17:55:30.97 Server      Using conventional memory in the memory manager.
2018-07-12 17:55:47.27 Server      This instance of SQL Server last reported using a process ID of 4400 at 12/07/2018 5:26:22 PM (local) 12/07/2018 9:26:22 AM (UTC). This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
2018-07-12 17:55:47.54 Server      Node configuration: node 0: CPU mask: 0x000000000000000f:0 Active CPU mask: 0x000000000000000f:0. This message provides a description of the NUMA configuration for this computer. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2018-07-12 17:55:47.56 Server      Using dynamic lock allocation.  Initial allocation of 2500 Lock blocks and 5000 Lock Owner blocks per node.  This is an informational message only.  No user action is required.
2018-07-12 17:55:47.59 Server      Software Usage Metrics is disabled.
2018-07-12 17:55:48.57 spid1s      Starting up database 'master'.
2018-07-12 17:55:49.53 Server      CLR version v4.0.30319 loaded.
2018-07-12 17:55:53.62 Server      Common language runtime (CLR) functionality initialized using CLR version v4.0.30319 from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\.
2018-07-12 17:56:09.76 spid1s      SQL Server Audit is starting the audits. This is an informational message. No user action is required.
2018-07-12 17:56:09.81 spid1s      SQL Server Audit has started the audits. This is an informational message. No user action is required.
2018-07-12 17:56:13.96 spid1s      SQL Trace ID 1 was started by login "sa".
2018-07-12 17:56:14.92 spid1s      Server name is 'NB-1608-001\SQLEXPRESS1'. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2018-07-12 17:56:16.22 spid12s     A self-generated certificate was successfully loaded for encryption.
2018-07-12 17:56:16.28 spid12s     Server is listening on [ 'any' <ipv6> 51270].
2018-07-12 17:56:16.28 spid12s     Server is listening on [ 'any' <ipv4> 51270].
2018-07-12 17:56:16.33 spid12s     Server local connection provider is ready to accept connection on [ \\.\pipe\SQLLocal\SQLEXPRESS1 ].
2018-07-12 17:56:16.33 spid12s     Server named pipe provider is ready to accept connection on [ \\.\pipe\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS1\sql\query ].
2018-07-12 17:56:16.33 spid12s     Dedicated administrator connection support was not started because it is disabled on this edition of SQL Server. If you want to use a dedicated administrator connection, restart SQL Server using the trace flag 7806. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2018-07-12 17:56:16.36 spid12s     SQL Server is now ready for client connections. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2018-07-12 17:56:16.36 Server      SQL Server is attempting to register a Service Principal Name (SPN) for the SQL Server service. Kerberos authentication will not be possible until a SPN is registered for the SQL Server service. This is an informational message. No user action is required.
2018-07-12 17:56:16.36 Server      The SQL Server Network Interface library could not register the Service Principal Name (SPN) [ MSSQLSvc/NB-1608-001:SQLEXPRESS1 ] for the SQL Server service. Windows return code: 0xffffffff, state: 53. Failure to register a SPN might cause integrated authentication to use NTLM instead of Kerberos. This is an informational message. Further action is only required if Kerberos authentication is required by authentication policies and if the SPN has not been manually registered.
2018-07-12 17:56:16.36 Server      The SQL Server Network Interface library could not register the Service Principal Name (SPN) [ MSSQLSvc/NB-1608-001:51270 ] for the SQL Server service. Windows return code: 0xffffffff, state: 53. Failure to register a SPN might cause integrated authentication to use NTLM instead of Kerberos. This is an informational message. Further action is only required if Kerberos authentication is required by authentication policies and if the SPN has not been manually registered.
2018-07-12 17:56:18.34 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.
2018-07-12 17:56:18.34 Logon       Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'ReportServer$SQLEXPRESS1'. [CLIENT: 192.168.0.100]
2018-07-12 17:56:25.44 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.
2018-07-12 17:56:25.44 Logon       Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'ReportServer$SQLEXPRESS1'. [CLIENT: 192.168.0.100]
2018-07-12 17:56:31.17 spid13s     Error: 9954, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2018-07-12 17:56:31.17 spid13s     SQL Server failed to communicate with filter daemon launch service  (Windows error: Windows Error: hr = 0x8007006d(failed to retrieve text for this error)). Full-Text filter daemon process failed to start. Full-text search functionality will not be available.
2018-07-12 17:56:31.57 spid1s      Starting up database 'msdb'.
```

First I changed to Service state to `Start Delay` but it does not work.

Second I changed to Log on properties and set to computer logon user's account but it does not work.

I am not sure why this error occurs and I cant find any useful resource.